# How can I create a multi layer pie chart with Highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am new in highchart and i want to create a pie chart in which some % of slice should be colored by darker version of it's color like below in picture.[image]

and if slices are **more than 8** than there is a slice **named "Others"** with **drilldown**.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your tries, post links, code ...

Comment: Perhaps you could consider a polar chart using column data. See the demo here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar

Comment: What does the source data look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple series. Each can have one pie slice with different `size`, `startAngle` and `endAngle`. Take a look at the example I posted below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.startAngle
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.endAngle
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.size

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yLkdfo3b/